# parse json data column

Tags: javascript, json, csv, google-visualization

I have a csv file which i read into a javascript variable. I now try to create a visualization for this.

```
   <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script></script>
    <script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/src/jquery.csv.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["motionchart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

      $.get("stockdata.csv", function(csvString) {  
 var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
  // this new DataTable object holds all the data
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
```

However, the second column in the data variable has to be type casted to a date. The string is already in yyyy-mm-dd format but this is not being accepted by the visualization. How can i convert only the second column into date type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply modify your data before visualizing it. The map function will collect every element of an object (or row of your array) and return it as a new array. You will modify each row in place before returning it.

```
arrayData = arrayData.map(function(row) {
   row[1] = new Date(row[1]);
   return row;
}
```